# Accessing running firefox over ssh

Tags: ssh, x11

I have a linux box in my office. I left a firefox window open there and came to home. I'd like to access the firefox window over ssh from my home. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Next time use vnc. Or just kill firefox, then run again in vnc. I hope it saves its state.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to start `x11vnc` or `vino-server` in that X session, port forward connections to that VNC server and attach to that.

For instance, with `$pid` the pid of firefox:

```
ssh -Y host vino-preferences
```

Enable sharing without prompt and set a VNC password.

```
ssh host
```

On the remote shell, run:

```
xargs -0a "/proc/$pid/environ" sh -c '
  exec env "$@"  /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --tube' sh
```

To start `vino`.

Note which port the vnc server is on.

Type `~C` to bring the ssh prompt, run (here if VNC is on port 2)

```
-L 5900:localhost:5902
```

to setup the port forward.

Then one the ssh client, connect to that VNC server with:

```
vinagre :0
```

(use a different port than 5900/:0 above if the VNC port is already in use on the local machine).

It's a bit simpler with `x11vnc`:

Run `vncpasswd` on the remote host to set a VNC password and:

```
xargs -0a "/proc/$pid/environ" sh -c '
  exec env "$@" x11vnc' sh
```

And proceed as above for the port forward and connecting to the VNC server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, no.  Your running firefox instance is talking to the X server on your desktop.

Depending on your desktop it may have built in "desktop sharing", which is typically a built-in VNC server.  You could connect to that and access your whole desktop remotely.

Alternatively there are solutions such as XPRA ( http://xpra.org/ ) which are "screen for X11"; you run the XPRA server, which creates an X server.  Inside that you can run your firefox, xterm, whatever.  And then attach to that server remotely.  But this requires pre-planning.